# How to put an icon inside textbox in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to put an icon inside textbox (should be at right end of the textbox, like clearText icon in search input type) in jquery mobile.
I have overridden some css classes of jquery mobile, still I couldn't achieve. Can someone please provide the solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple solution is to put your text box and image into a div that is relatively positioned. Then you set the image position to `absolute` and give it the needed `right` value.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <img src="http://the-dream.co.uk/images/lens_icon.png" width="15" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:200px
}

input{
    width:200px;
}

img{
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
}
```

---

Check that fiddle for a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8sbpn/1/

Comment: ya its working :) Thanks a lot for your quick response, I didn't try with right and top attributes for img. Its awesome :). Thank you once again :)

Comment: Welcome. Remember that right,left,top and bottom attributes work with all elements, not just images.

Comment: Ok, this is a great learning for me :) and this is the first time that I found the importance of keeping relative for div

Comment: Instead of <img>, you can also stick the font awesome CSS.  <i class="srchlens fa fa-search fa-1"></i>