# Place an image inside a text field

Tags: html, css, image

I have an HTML input field like this. I would like to place an image inside the textbox on the right side. Can someone help me out with its CSS for that?

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
```

[image]

In the picture is an image which is inside the text field email address, which is what I want. How do you do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839771/how-to-put-an-icon-inside-textbox-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/zy7YP/1/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="fake-input">
    <input type="text" />
    <img src="http://www.zermatt-fun.ch/images/mastercard.jpg" width=25 />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fake-input { position: relative; width:240px; }
.fake-input input { border:none; background-color:#fff; display:block; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box }
.fake-input img { position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 5px }
```

**Working demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/HnJZa/

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
input { 
  background-image: url("icon.png");
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try something like this

```
.textBox{  
background-image:url(iconimage.jpg);   
background-position:right;   
background-repeat:no-repeat;   
padding-left:17px;
}
```

Then apply this style to your text box:

```
<input type="text" class="textBox" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use background-image and background-position property

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/a5WFZ/)

CSS:

```
input  {
     height: 70px;
     width: 200px;
     background-image:url("http://cloud.ohloh.net/attachments/25869/plone-icon-64_med.png");
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position: 133px 3px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.text3 {
 width: 300px;
 height: 30px;
}

#text3 {
 background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-8/128/InterfaceExpendet-09-128.png);
 background-size: 30px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="email">
   Email
</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Email_ID" class="text3" id="text3">
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers above didn't replicate the format shown in the questioners image, or provide any explanation.  This is a solution using background images.

Explanation of the background image syntax.

```
background: url('https://d1ululg65bfe3q.cloudfront.net/images/troy/email-icon.png') no-repeat 97.25% 10px white;
```

- Location of image: url('https://d1ululg65bfe3q.cloudfront.net/images/troy/email-icon.png')
- Show image once: no-repeat
- Distance from left: 97.25%
- Distance from top: 10px
- Background color: white

```css
.bg-email-icon {
  background: url('https://d1ululg65bfe3q.cloudfront.net/images/troy/email-icon.png') no-repeat 97.25% 10px white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 255px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.bg-lock-icon {
  background: url('https://d1ululg65bfe3q.cloudfront.net/images/troy/lock-icon.png') no-repeat 96.75% 10px white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 255px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<input name="exampleEmail" class="bg-email-icon" placeholder="Email" type="email">
<input name="examplePassword" class="bg-lock-icon" placeholder="Password" type="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to your input

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="inputImage" />
```

and then background image to class in css

```
.inputImage
{
background:#FFFFFF url('img.jpg') no-repeat top right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class like this:

**CSS:**

```
.bgInput {
  background: url(path of your image.jpg) top right no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="bgInput" id="name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small answer: you can do this by setting as a background image of input field.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#name {
      background: url('path/image.png') right no-repeat;
}
```