# Displaying an Image in Search Bar HTML

Tags: html, css

I am finishing up this table and I added a search function to it. But in the search bar, I want to put a search icon png file for the background image just like the example on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp). I put it in the myInput field, but either nothing appears in the search bar, or it is so massive you can see a tiny top corner piece of the search icon and I cant figure out how to fix it.

[image: Post Background Size edit]

[image: Search box input element]

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-512.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Comment: Give me a second I have to shave a bunch of stuff out of my code if I want to do that because I have all the javascript/css/html in one file and its populating the table from info from a sharepoint site so that wont be able to work here

Comment: you probably have to adjust the background position, also i cant think that this is a crossbrowser solution. you would rather prepend an element good luck

Comment: @David just use this as an example, it is what I am trying to achieve but my table is way more complex https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

Comment: Are you sure the image URL is correct? In other words, does it show up if you put it in an img tag?

Comment: @Uuuuuumm yes I am positive I even just tested it out to double check

Comment: It has something to do with the image, though. If I substitute your image URL into the W3Schools example, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [background-size](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property. Because the image is larger than the input, you are seeing a white portion of the picture. By setting the property to `contain` the image is shrunk to the size of your `input`.

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-512.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Search..." type="text" id="myInput">
```

Note: You should also set the `background-position` property to 0 or remove it all together; otherwise, the search icon will be skewed to the right and downwards.
If instead you want to make the icon smaller, change `background-position` to `left center` and set `background-size` to a px value of your choice.

Comment: That almost worked... Look at the image in my recent edit

Comment: @zgoforth It's because your `background-position` is still set at 10px, so it's skewed down and to the right. Set it to `0px 0px` and it will work. I will update my answer to include this explanation

Comment: Marvin you are the greatest! Thank you

Comment: is there anyway you know to maybe make the image a bit smaller so it isnt massive compared to the text?

Comment: @zgoforth You are most welcome! If my answer worked for you, be sure to accept the answer by clicking the check.

Comment: I know what to do, I had one more question I was hoping you could help me with which I asked right above your most recent response

Comment: @zgoforth Yes, I see. See my edit to the post - I have updated it answering your second question

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="fake-input">
    <input type="text" />
    <img src="http://www.zermatt-fun.ch/images/mastercard.jpg" width=25 />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fake-input { position: relative; width:240px; }
.fake-input input { border:none; background-color:#fff; display:block; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box }
.fake-input img { position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 5px }
```

[Source is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740523/place-an-image-inside-a-text-field)

Comment: The user wants the icon on the left, not the right. Also, why is the class named "fake-input"?

Comment: he can update the css, its just an example to start, fake-input is ust class name :)